# How to access smarty variable on all pages, which is assigned into one page by default

Tags: smarty, prestashop

Hi I need to access in prestashop smarty variables, which are not by default avaible on all pages.
Specificly $compareProducts and $comparator_max_item on main page(index page).

Could somebody tell me how can I do this (access them on all pages) without overriding prestashop core?

Comment: Isn't it better to create standalone module for specific purposes? I find your way little intrusive and update-error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

With PrestaShop it's possible to override controller.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors

Edit this file :

/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php

with :

```
<?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function process()
    {
        parent::process();

        $this->context->smarty->assign('comparator_max_item', (int)(Configuration::get('PS_COMPARATOR_MAX_ITEM')));
    }
}
```

Prestashop core is not updated but simply overriden with others class and it's possible of updating later your prestashop version.

*PS : Sample for Prestashop v1.5*